# Calling a Javascript function via ssl

Tags: javascript, ssl, iframe, https, static-ip-address

Please excuse any ignorance on my part, I am very new to SSL and Javascript, so what I am asking may be obvious.  I have tried to Google but can't seem to find the answer to my question.

**Background**

Basically, I have a website, with a subdomain that holds a rental car booking engine in an iframe, which is called from an external location using Javascript.  We recently moved to SSL and now the booking engine does not display as it is deemed unsecure by web browsers.

I contacted the company that manages the booking engine and they advised that I needed an SSL for the subdomain, which they can load at their end as well (I bought a single domain, not a wildcard, my mistake), and I needed to purchase a static IP on their server. They sent me a quote for €130 per year for and a static IP.

My very limited knowledge of SSL seems to suggest that a static IP is not required, however I am probably wrong about this.

**Question**

Do I need the static IP for the SSL to work, or will the wildcard SSL resolve the issue?

I understand that the SSL for the subdomain is required, I just can't find an answer for the static IP.

Basically, I don't fully trust the company as they have tried to add unnecessary charges to invoices in the past.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is somewhat off-topic on SO. SSL used to need a dedicated IP address (e.g. only one site per IP) but this is no longer true when using SNI which is widely supported now.

Comment: I suppose what I am asking is whether SNI is relevant if I am calling the javascript in an iframe.

Comment: SNI is an alternative way of negotiating the SSL connection, it has nothing at all to do with what happens after the connection is established. Still this is not a programming question...

Comment: Thanks, is there a more relevant place to ask this question?  After more research, I think that the static IP is not required, however I still don't fully understand

Comment: I think https://superuser.com would fit better.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to add SSL certificate to your subdomain to make browsers detect its safe, since the calls will be made to a non SSL domain from a SSL certified domain. I would suggest you to take a look at [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) which provides free ssl and you can add as much sub domains as you want. I am using it for one of my projects and have added more than 5 ssl certifactes for subdomains.

Comment: Thanks Noushad, my question was do I need the static IP address on their server?

Comment: The IP address for an SSL does NOT need to be static. The problem you're going to have with hosting an SSL service on a dynamic IP address is that you will need to set up your DNS to 'follow' your IP address around.

Comment: By the way, which service do you use for hosting?

Comment: You can use name based ```<VirtualHost />``` setting using apache or nginx for setting up ssl also